# EF Code First The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, runtime-error, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

When I try to insert a record in the database, I get this error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Order_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Test", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

*Disclaimer: I know that this question has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185991/in-code-first-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828467/ef-code-first-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584278/what-causes-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)), but none of answers helped me fix this error I get.*

Here are the models:

```
[Table("Order")]
public class Order
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }      

    public virtual List<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}    

[Table("OrderDetails")]
public class OrderDetails
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Code that inserts the new `Order`:

```
public OrderDetails Add(dynamic addOrderDetails, string userId)
{
    if (addOrderDetails.OrderId == null)
    {
        var order = new Order()
        {
            UserId = userId,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            Status = OStatus.InProgress,
            Confirmed = (DateTime?)null,
        };

        var newOrder = _dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
        _dbContext.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Added;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges(); // this is where the error msg is being thrown.

        var orderDetails = new OrderDetails()
        {
            OrderId = newOrder.Id,
            ServiceId = addOrderDetails.ServiceId,
            EventStart = start,
            EventEnd = end
        };

        var newOrderDetails = _dbContext.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetails);
        _dbContext.Entry(orderDetails).State = EntityState.Added;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The error is being thrown at this line: `_dbContext.SaveChanges(); // this is where the error msg is being thrown.`

When debugging I can see that `UserId = userId,` has a value.

So why am I getting this error message?

Comment: I've always done DB first, but looks to me like it can't find anything in ApplicationUsers that satisfies UserID in your new Order. Which initially suggests the user isn't in the ApplicationUsers table, but on looking at your entity for that table I don't see where UserID even exists..?

Comment: `IdentityUser` which replaces the `MembershipProvider` and the `SimpleMembershipProvider` contains the UserId by default, and some more fields. `asp.net-identity` tag added to the post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `AspNetUsers` table in the database must contain a record whose `UserId` column has the value you set with `userId` in the new order. `Order.UserId` is not only required but also a foreign key to the `AspNetUsers` table (see the `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` attribute in `Order`). So, it's not enough that `Order.UserId` has *any* value (!= null), it must have a value that corresponds to a record in the `AspNetUsers` table.

The exception means that such a record is not present in the `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, and I figured it out yesterday. The `UserId` is a `varchar` in the database (`GUID` format). What happened is, is that I deleted the database and recreated it, but in IE I checked the box 'remember me' when I still had the previous database. So when I started the application again, I was logged in. And it remembered my old user information. That's why I had this error. Didn't bother to check if the `UserId` actually existed in the database.

Comment: Had been staring at this for half an hour... thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_dbo.Order_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in
> database "Test", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'. The statement
> has been terminated.

This means that the individual order (row) at `Order_dbo` CANNOT be created without a reference to **an existing** user at `AspNetUsers`.

This error is coming from the actual DB, that's why you're getting it when you reach `_dbContext.SaveChanges()`, and not before.

## Possible solution

Make the column `AspNetUsers_UserId` nullable.

```cs
[Required]
public int? UserId { get; set; }
```

That way you´ll be able to create orders without having a previously set user.

I suggest you to use `int` instead of `string` type for you Id.